# Why does a rigid body rotates about it's centre of mass?

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics

When an impulsive force is acted upon a rigid body, (and the force doesn't pass through the centre of mass) why does the body rotates specifically about an axis passing through centre of mass ?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/151374/ 
I think you'll find your answer here

Comment: Who says it does? Look up [*center of percussion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_percussion).

Comment: Another possible duplicate : [What is the proof that a force applied on a rigid body will cause it to rotate around its center of mass?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53465)

Answer (score 0):

An impulsive force directed along a line crossing the center of mass doesn't produce a torque relative to this center. It causes only a linear momentum change, i.e., a translational movement and no rotation of the body. Any other impulsive force  on the body produces a torque relative to the center of mass causing an angular acceleration of the body around the center of mass (and a linear acceleration). This results in a constant angular momentum, i.e., a constant rotation of the body around an axis through the center of mass after the impulsive force has ended. A free floating rotating body always rotates around an axis going through its center of mass.

Comment: The first sentence is a bit hard-to-read, please consider an improvement.