# When is it possible for torque to be equal to the product of moment of inertia and angular velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

From angular mechanics I am trying to figure out where an equation used by my textbook comes from

$$\Delta \omega = \frac{r \times J}{I}$$

where $J$ is the linear impulse. [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302833/impulse-and-angular-velocity) answer derives that formula but it uses $\tau = I\omega$ to get there. I am not sure how this can be reconciled with the usual definition that I have seen $\tau=I\alpha$ and I am also not sure about the definition of $J$ used in the answer. Thanks for any pointers to help me figure this out!

Comment: $\tau=I\omega$ is dimensionally inconsistent and therefore wrong/impossible/nonsense. The definition of $\mathbf J$ in the [linked answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302833/impulse-and-angular-velocity) is also nonsense; the time derivative of momentum is force, not impulse. Don’t assume that a PSE answer is correct just because it gets accepted! I’ve just downvoted it.

Comment: *Thanks for any pointers to help me figure this out!* Dimensional analysis is a critical skill for doing physics. I highly recommend learning how to do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $i$ is _not_ a scalar quantity and you cannot generally create a fraction with it the denominator.  Are you thinking of $$\Delta \vec{ \omega } = I^{-1} ( \vec{r} \times \vec{J} )$$ where $\vec{J}$ is an impulse acting a distance $\vec{r}$ from the center of mass.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou The textbook did not present it like that but you are exactly right that is what I am trying to derive! Apologies, in this example the object is constrained to be a plane in the xy axis and the "moment of inertia" is actually only a scalar representing rotation around the z-axis. I was so caught up trying to figure out where the formula came from that I forgot to mention this important detail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $$ \Delta \boldsymbol{\omega} = {\rm I}_C^{-1} ( \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{J} ) \tag{1}$$

where $\boldsymbol{J}$ is an impulse vector, acting through a point located at $\boldsymbol{r}$ relative to the center of mass, and $\mathrm{I}_C$ is the mass moment of inertia 3×3 *tensor* and $\Delta \boldsymbol{\omega}$ is the resulting change in angular velocity, is derived from combining two equations.

<sub>*I use **boldface italic** letters for vectors, and* upright *letters for matrices*.</sub>

- Angular momentum of a rigid body about the center of mass is $$\boldsymbol{L}_C = {\rm I}_C \, \boldsymbol{\omega} \tag{2}$$

  This is derived from the summation of each particle's contribution to angular momentum. $\boldsymbol{L}_C = \sum_i \boldsymbol{r}_i \times (m_i \boldsymbol{v}_i)$ when each particle is rotating about the center of mass with $\boldsymbol{v}_i = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{r}_i$.
- Angular momentum of a single particle (or point object) located at $\boldsymbol{r}$ with momentum $\boldsymbol{p}$ $$ \boldsymbol{L} = \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{p} \tag{3}$$

  without loss of generality you can assume the impulse $\boldsymbol{J}$ is a result of a *complete* momentum transfer from a point mass hitting the object with $\boldsymbol{J}=\boldsymbol{p}$. Also due to the conservation of angular momentum the angular momentum of the body after the impact equals the angular momentum of the point mass before impact, $\boldsymbol{L}_C = \boldsymbol{L}$.

So together you have

$$ \boldsymbol{L}_C = \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{J} = \mathrm{I}_C \Delta \boldsymbol{\omega} \tag{4}$$

which is solved for the change in motion as

$$\Delta \boldsymbol{\omega} = {\rm I}^{-1}_C ( \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{J} ) $$

Answer (score 0):

Linear impulse, $J=$ force $\times$ time so in terms of dimensions you have,

$\Delta \omega = \dfrac{r \times J}{I} \Rightarrow I\,\Delta \omega = r \times J \Rightarrow$ (M L$^2$) (T$^{-1}$) = (L) (M L T$^{-2}$) (T)

which is dimensionally correct and noting the linear equivalent with change in linear momentum is equal to the impulse.