# Confusion about torque

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

Consider a free body, not hinged about any point. If a force is applied to one end of the body, the body has a net nonzero torque about many points in space. About which will it rotate? Am I wrong in thinking that it will rotate at all?

Note that I am not asking about a couple, but a single force.

I asked [a similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/781159/why-does-a-free-body-rotate-about-centre-of-mass-when-torque-is-applied) a few days before, but it got closed, with links not at all answering my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I push or hit an object in space will it rotate or move along a straight line?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235482/)

Comment: You move the force parallel to its line of action to the COM and add a force couple equal to the torque produced by the force at its original location about the COM. This is an equivalent force couple system. It has the same external effect on the rigid body as the force had at its original location

Answer (score 0):

The body will rotate about the centre of mass. The body will also undergo translation. If the force is applied at the centre of mass, the body will undergo pure translation.

Comment: Why would it rotate about the C.O.M? Can you please provide some more detail?

Comment: @Eisenstein because the moment of inertia about the centre of mass is minimum

Comment: Yes, I too read about that in a similar question. But why does minimum moment of inertia ensure maximum stability?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by stability here. But all processes tend to happen through the path of least resistance. Minimum moment of inertia implies a minimum resistance to rotation.

Comment: "But all processes tend to happen through the path of least resistance" Can you provide some sources to further read up on this?

Comment: this is more of a explanation used to satisfy a layperson. There are other ways to look at the problem you posted. Here are some related questions http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53465/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81029/2451

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the torque $~\vec\tau~$ is

$$\vec\tau=\vec{r}_{Ao}\times \vec F=r\,F\,\underbrace{(\hat e_{Ao}\times \hat e_F)}_{\hat e_\tau}$$

where A is arbitrary  rigid body point

thus the rotation of the rigid   is at point A about the axis  $~\hat e_\tau$